# WCF over Named Pipes throws exception in .NET4, works in 3.5

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, named-pipes

I'm trying to run this example derived from this blog entry on 

[WCF Tutorial - Basic Interprocess Communication](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication)

If I run the server code in .NET4, it throws the following exception:

```
First-chance exception at 0x754cd36f (KernelBase.dll) in TestConsole.exe: 0xE0564552: 0xe0564552.
```

If I run the server code in .NET3.5, it works just fine. Client code is compiled against .NET4 in both tests.  My server code is as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStringReverser
{
    [OperationContract]
    string ReverseString(string value);
}

public class StringReverser : IStringReverser
{
    public string ReverseString(string value)
    {
        char[] retVal = value.ToCharArray();
        int idx = 0;
        for (int i = value.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            retVal[idx++] = value[i];

        return new string(retVal);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(StringReverser), new Uri[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") }))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStringReverser), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "PipeReverse");
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Service is available. Press <ENTER> to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

My client code is as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStringReverser
{
    [OperationContract]
    string ReverseString(string value);
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IStringReverser> pipeFactory =
          new ChannelFactory<IStringReverser>(
            new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress(
              "net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse"));

        IStringReverser pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

        while (true)
        {
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("pipe: " +
              pipeProxy.ReverseString(str));
        }
    }
}
```

Why on earth is this failing on .NET4?  Seems like a pretty basic example.  I did do a clean/build between each run.  Here is a snapshot of the actual stacktrace:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had the "throw" checked in Debug -> Exceptions -> C++ Exceptions while in Visual Studio.  If I don't throw the exception, but let it be handled, everything works fine.